# Where to download QGIS 2.10?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, windows, download, qgis-2.10

Is QGIS 2.10 Pisa for Ubuntu/Windows already available?

Comment: weekly build is up to 2.9.0.25 for windows http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/ (I am looking for a windows 10 compatible version too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ubuntu/Debian packages for 2.10.0 are already listed at http://qgis.org/debian/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages but not yet announced.

Apart from that, you can already compile from source: http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2.10.0.tar.bz2

---

**UPDATE 22-07-2015**

QGIS 2.10.1 is now available for most platforms from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. Thanks to the devs for late bugfixing and patience on the user side.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you can use the [OSGeo4W Installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) which has 2.10.0-1 included.

I don't think the Ubuntu/Debian package is ready just yet, since the [official QGIS page](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) still lists 2.9 as developement.

Comment: still getting for OSGeo4W (on Windows 10 VM) This version of C:\PROGRA-1\QGISWE-1\bin\gdalinfo.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows your're running.

Comment: @Mapperz - [This blog](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=sv&u=https://geosupportsystem.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/windows-10-qgis/&prev=search) mentioned recently that there may be a compatability issue between QGIS 2.10 and Windows 10. Hopefully the developers will fix this soon. (_Note the blog was originally in Swedish_)