# QGIS 2.10 Can't load georeference plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, fedora

Apparently my problem was already present in older versions of Qgis. I don't know how to fix it, knowing I have a Linux system (Fedora 23).
Somethiing similar here :
[Where to download QGIS 2.10?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152935/where-to-download-qgis-2-10)

So, I cannot found this plugin, neither Fetch Python Plugins command, but not it would fix anything anyway since georeference is within GDAL. I had installed  Qgis on this system (fedora 23) for first time (no older version).

Otherwise the procedure to download the plugin should be that one : http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html
but I do not find georeference into the list of available plugins. The repository I use is the default one : http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Comment: it is a core plugin

Comment: How did you install your QGIS? Did you install qgis-python package mentioned at https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/qgis-python ? If yes, you should get access to the plugins menu and activate *Georeferencer GDAL*

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yes it is installed as well, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: So I had reinstall the whole Qgis and plugins, but notjhing better. I still do not see the georeferencer into the list of plugins. Anyway to do it manually ?... or do it by anyway ?

Comment: @Deun - From the _Processing_ toolbar, go to **Commander** and type `georeferencer`. Does it show up then?

Comment: I got an : Error wrong command

Comment: have you tried the plugin settings? Georeference GDAL is an experimental plugin so it will only appear if you select the checkbox that says "Show also experimental plugins"

Comment: Well I did not thunk it might be experimental. So I had checked it and nothing new (except a module called GeorefExport which is not the one I need).